# Installation lighthouse in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Describe the bug
the lighthouse does not install on laravel 5.7

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install nuwave/lighthouse v2.6.4
    - Conclusion: don't install nuwave/lighthouse v2.6.3
    - Conclusion: don't install nuwave/lighthouse v2.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install nuwave/lighthouse v2.6.1
    - Conclusion: don't install nuwave/lighthouse v2.6.0
    - Conclusion: remove webonyx/graphql-php v0.13.1
    - Installation request for nuwave/lighthouse ^2.6 
      -> satisfiable by nuwave/lighthouse[2.x-dev, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4].
    - Conclusion: don't install webonyx/graphql-php v0.13.1
    - nuwave/lighthouse 2.x-dev requires webonyx/graphql-php ^0.12 
      -> satisfiable by webonyx/graphql-php[0.12.x-dev, v0.12.0, v0.12.1, v0.12.2, v0.12.3, v0.12.4, v0.12.5, v0.12.6].
    - Can only install one of: webonyx/graphql-php[0.12.x-dev, v0.13.1].
    - Can only install one of: webonyx/graphql-php[v0.12.0, v0.13.1].
    - Can only install one of: webonyx/graphql-php[v0.12.1, v0.13.1].
    - Can only install one of: webonyx/graphql-php[v0.12.2, v0.13.1].
    - Can only install one of: webonyx/graphql-php[v0.12.3, v0.13.1].
    - Can only install one of: webonyx/graphql-php[v0.12.4, v0.13.1].
    - Can only install one of: webonyx/graphql-php[v0.12.5, v0.13.1].
    - Can only install one of: webonyx/graphql-php[v0.12.6, v0.13.1].
    - Installation request for webonyx/graphql-php (locked at v0.13.1) 
      -> satisfiable by webonyx/graphql-php[v0.13.1].
```

Comment: The problem looks like you had `webonyx/graphql-php` installed beforehand and your version of it has a conflict with Lighthouse version of it.

Comment: I got this same error. The reason was I have installed another graphql package. rebing/graphql-laravel. Once I remove that the installation works well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing Laravel 5.7 project, all you really need is two steps:

1. Install via `composer require nuwave/lighthouse`
2. Define your schema in `graphql/schema.graphql`

According to [nuwave/lighthouse](https://packagist.org/packages/nuwave/lighthouse) package you need to `php: >= 7.1`

Apart from this, you also need to complete the package's requirement in your project